# How to detect user input as "zero" and force user to give valid reason in text box given

Tags: php, html

html code is given as below :

```
<tr>
     <td>i</td>
     <td colspan="3">Temperature Of Warming Bin/Chute(140F -150F/60C - 65C)</td>
       <td>1</td>
        <td>
        class="col-sm-12">
        <input required type="number" class="form-control" name="b_1_1" id="b_1_1" min="0" max="1">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And my comment box in html is :

```
<div class="form-group">
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Comments" name="Comments" id="Comments" rows="6"></textarea></div>
```

How to force a user to give valid reason if the user input is "0" instead "1" in a textarea below before proceeding to next form. I have a total of 5 forms.

Comment: Try with js jquery for this , to check `0` and ask reason

Comment: can you elaborate more on that? providing code will be so much helpful. thanks.

Comment: @KirthanaGovindarajaoo Check the answers below

Answer (score 0):

You should use some Javascript library to validate user input. You can achieve this using jQuery for example:

```
$('#IdOfYourForm').on('submit', function(e) { // trigger this when the form is submitted
    e.preventDefault();// stop the form from submitting
    var min = $('#b_1_1').attr('min'); // min value of the element's attribute min = "0"
    var max = $('#b_1_1').attr('max'); // max value of the element's attribute max = "1"
    var userInput = $('#b_1_1').val();
    if (userInput == min) { // if the user entered a value equals to the value in the min ="0" attribute then ask reason
        // alert him with a pop-up or something to ask for the reason.
    } else if (userInput == max) { // if the user input = maximum
        $(this).submit();// submit the form and move on to the next form
    } else { // if the user inputs something that is neither 1 or 0 like 5 for example
        // alert an error 
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have to add this jQuery in html itself or how, because i have around 50 questions where user  have to key in either 1 or 0?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to do this so:
If you want to do it with php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['b_1_1']) && $_POST['b_1_1'] == 0){
    echo '<div class="form-group"><textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Comments" name="Comments" id="Comments" rows="6"></textarea></div>';
}
```

---

If you want to do it with JS:

```
document.querySelector('#Comments').style.display = 'none';
document.querySelector('#b_1_1').addEventListener("change", function(){
    if(this.value == 0) document.querySelector('#Comments').style.display = 'block';
});
```